# Как распарсить json-файл?

Tags: java, json, парсер

Получаю *JSON*-файл с https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=01.12.2014, дата не имеет значения в данном случае, она может быть другая, т.к. вводится пользователем с консоли.

Мне нужно вывести только курс доллара, вопрос состоит в том, как мне вытянуть оттуда только курс доллара?

Сам json-файл прилагаю:

```
{
   "date":"01.12.2014",
   "bank":"PB",
   "baseCurrency":980,
   "baseCurrencyLit":"UAH",
   "exchangeRate":[
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"AUD",
         "saleRateNB":12.8319250,
         "purchaseRateNB":12.8319250
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"CAD",
         "saleRateNB":13.2107400,
         "purchaseRateNB":13.2107400,
         "saleRate":15.0000000,
         "purchaseRate":13.0000000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"CZK",
         "saleRateNB":0.6796950,
         "purchaseRateNB":0.6796950,
         "saleRate":0.8000000,
         "purchaseRate":0.6000000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"DKK",
         "saleRateNB":2.5258930,
         "purchaseRateNB":2.5258930
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"HUF",
         "saleRateNB":0.0612592,
         "purchaseRateNB":0.0612592
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"ILS",
         "saleRateNB":3.8627380,
         "purchaseRateNB":3.8627380,
         "saleRate":4.5000000,
         "purchaseRate":3.7000000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"JPY",
         "saleRateNB":0.1272593,
         "purchaseRateNB":0.1272593,
         "saleRate":0.1500000,
         "purchaseRate":0.1200000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"LVL",
         "saleRateNB":0.1272593,
         "purchaseRateNB":0.1272593
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"LTL",
         "saleRateNB":5.4433850,
         "purchaseRateNB":5.4433850
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"NOK",
         "saleRateNB":2.1609570,
         "purchaseRateNB":2.1609570,
         "saleRate":2.6000000,
         "purchaseRate":2.1000000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"SKK",
         "saleRateNB":2.1609570,
         "purchaseRateNB":2.1609570
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"SEK",
         "saleRateNB":2.0283750,
         "purchaseRateNB":2.0283750
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"CHF",
         "saleRateNB":15.6389750,
         "purchaseRateNB":15.6389750,
         "saleRate":17.0000000,
         "purchaseRate":15.5000000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"RUB",
         "saleRateNB":0.3052700,
         "purchaseRateNB":0.3052700,
         "saleRate":0.3200000,
         "purchaseRate":0.2800000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"GBP",
         "saleRateNB":23.6324910,
         "purchaseRateNB":23.6324910,
         "saleRate":25.8000000,
         "purchaseRate":24.0000000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"USD",
         "saleRateNB":15.0564130,
         "purchaseRateNB":15.0564130,
         "saleRate":15.7000000,
         "purchaseRate":15.3500000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"BYR",
         "saleRateNB":0.0013900,
         "purchaseRateNB":0.0013900
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"EUR",
         "saleRateNB":18.7949200,
         "purchaseRateNB":18.7949200,
         "saleRate":20.0000000,
         "purchaseRate":19.2000000
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"GEL",
         "saleRateNB":8.1500890,
         "purchaseRateNB":8.1500890
      },
      {
         "baseCurrency":"UAH",
         "currency":"PLZ",
         "saleRateNB":4.4922010,
         "purchaseRateNB":4.4922010,
         "saleRate":5.0000000,
         "purchaseRate":4.2000000
      }
   ]
}
```

Еще код, с помощью которого я получаю информацию с сервера:

```
public class HttpUtil {


public static String sendRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers, String request) {
    String result = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL requestUrl = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        if (request != null) {
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(request);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }

        if (headers != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("status code:" + status);

        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            result = getStringFromStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("sendRequest failed");
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static String getStringFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    ByteArrayOutputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BUFFER_SIZE);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        resultStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return resultStream.toString("UTF-8");
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String enteredDate = enterDate();
    String url = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=";
    String result = HttpUtil.sendRequest(url, null, null);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создаете 2 класса, которые описывают Вашу структуру:

   ```
   class Basic {
       private String date;
       private String bank;
       private String baseCurrency;
       private String baseCurrencyLit;
       private List<Inner> exchangeRate;

       public String getDate() {
           return date;
       }

       public void setDate(String date) {
           this.date = date;
       }

       public String getBank() {
           return bank;
       }

       public void setBank(String bank) {
           this.bank = bank;
       }

       public String getBaseCurrency() {
           return baseCurrency;
       }

       public void setBaseCurrency(String baseCurrency) {
           this.baseCurrency = baseCurrency;
       }

       public String getBaseCurrencyLit() {
           return baseCurrencyLit;
       }

       public void setBaseCurrencyLit(String baseCurrencyLit) {
           this.baseCurrencyLit = baseCurrencyLit;
       }

       public List<Inner> getExchangeRate() {
           return exchangeRate;
       }

       public void setExchangeRate(List<Inner> exchangeRate) {
           this.exchangeRate = exchangeRate;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Basic{" +
                   "date='" + date + '\'' +
                   ", bank='" + bank + '\'' +
                   ", baseCurrency='" + baseCurrency + '\'' +
                   ", baseCurrencyLit='" + baseCurrencyLit + '\'' +
                   ", exchangeRate=" + Arrays.toString(exchangeRate.toArray()) +
                   '}';
       }
   }

   class Inner {
       private String baseCurrency;
       private String currency;
       private String saleRateNB;
       private String purchaseRateNB;
       private String saleRate;
       private String purchaseRate;

       public String getBaseCurrency() {
           return baseCurrency;
       }

       public void setBaseCurrency(String baseCurrency) {
           this.baseCurrency = baseCurrency;
       }

       public String getCurrency() {
           return currency;
       }

       public void setCurrency(String currency) {
           this.currency = currency;
       }

       public String getSaleRateNB() {
           return saleRateNB;
       }

       public void setSaleRateNB(String saleRateNB) {
           this.saleRateNB = saleRateNB;
       }

       public String getPurchaseRateNB() {
           return purchaseRateNB;
       }

       public void setPurchaseRateNB(String purchaseRateNB) {
           this.purchaseRateNB = purchaseRateNB;
       }

       public String getSaleRate() {
           return saleRate;
       }

       public void setSaleRate(String saleRate) {
           this.saleRate = saleRate;
       }

       public String getPurchaseRate() {
           return purchaseRate;
       }

       public void setPurchaseRate(String purchaseRate) {
           this.purchaseRate = purchaseRate;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Inner{" +
                   "baseCurrency='" + baseCurrency + '\'' +
                   ", currency='" + currency + '\'' +
                   ", saleRateNB='" + saleRateNB + '\'' +
                   ", purchaseRateNB='" + purchaseRateNB + '\'' +
                   ", saleRate='" + saleRate + '\'' +
                   ", purchaseRate='" + purchaseRate + '\'' +
                   '}';
       }
   }
   ```
2. Используя Gson:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>2.8.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

, десериализуете Ваш JSON в Ваш объект:

```
    Basic basic = new Gson().fromJson([ваш json], Basic.class);
    System.out.println(basic);
```

Как получить именно доллар, я думаю Вы разберетесь.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, направили в нужное русло, все вышло)